# pbuilder create err

Tags: debian, pbuilder

I am trying to create `pbuilder`.
When I do `sudo create pbuilder`, I get following error:

```
E: Failed getting release file http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/sid/Release
E: debootstrap failed
```

Infact http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/sid/Release is not accessible. How can I configure a valid source link?

Comment: There is no security support for Sid, which is why there is no repository there. What did you do before `sudo pbuilder --create`?

Comment: I have just installed debian stretch 9. I installed pbuilder as i wanted to Debianize a package in pbuilder. I then just initiated 'pbuilder create' to generate  /var/cache/pbuilder/base.tgz and it is giving this error now

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install "sid" by giving the option `--mirror http://ftp.debian.org/debian`.

Even though in my example I'm using "cowbuilder", it's actually a wrapper for "pbuilder":

```bsh
cowbuilder --create --distribution sid --basepath /var/cache/pbuilder/base-sid.cow --mirror http://ftp.debian.org/debian
```